# How do I password protect a file in terminal?

Tags: macos, security, terminal, passwords

I have additions to the `sudo/hosts` file that blocks access to websites, like this.

```
0.0.0.0 randomwebsite.com
::      randomwebsite.com
```

I'd like to make it so the file is locked with a password. Right now, I can only edit it with sudo access, but I'd like to set a password separate from the admin password. How do I do that from terminal?

Comment: I'm not sure you can arbitrarily attach passwords to files.  As a workaround you could change the group ownership on that file to some special group that only has one user, so people can su to that user instead of su root.

Comment: I know how to set a group with chown. How do I create a user for that group?

Comment: I believe it's done with the `adduser` command.